# translate a range object in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say I do the following to hightlight the last column in a tabular list:

```
    Range("K2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Let's assume for the sake of this example, as a result of these commands, the hightlighted range is K2:K40.

Column L is currently empty.

Is there any way to translate the currently highlighted range over one column? So L2:L40 ends up highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Range.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx) property

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1).Select
```